# Engineering a Sort Function

Tags: algorithm, sorting

i was reading [Engineering a Sort Function(pg-1254)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf) in which JON L. BENTLEY & M. DOUGLAS McILROY discussed about 2 type of cost model

> MIX: overhead = comparisons < swaps
>
> qsort: overhead < swaps < comparisons

[(page no-1254 of Engineering a Sort Function)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

can any one explain me why comparisons is too much costly in second model except strings case ?
if comparison is really too much costly then why we are not using "bottom up heapsort" ??

according to wikipedia,

[It is a variant of Heapsort which is particularly suitable for the sorting of very large amounts of data, if a relatively high cost per compare operation is needed and on average better than Quicksort](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BottomUp-Heapsort)

Comment: Please modify your question so that it is possible to understand it without reading the linked article. It isn't clear what these models you are talking about are, or what "strings case" means. And your wikipedia link is in German.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why comparisons are expensive is in the next sentence:

> The second model reflects the generality of the `qsort` interface, in which comparison is a
>   function, not a machine primitive.

This is also true of strings. In fact, it is especially true of strings, since comparing two strings involves a function call, pointer indirection (goodbye locality of reference) and walking the two strings, doing min(*m*, *n*) byte comparisons where *m*, *n* are the lengths of the strings.

> if comparison is really too much costly then why we are not using "bottom up heapsort" ?

You should ask the authors.

Answer (score 0):

When the keys are accessed indirectly (via an array of pointers or similar), the cost of swapping is related to the size of the reference info; the cost of comparing is always related to the size of the keys. So the cost of the swapping can become negligible.